# Where can I find machine-consumeable documents of the java syntax?

Tags: java, syntax

I would like to know if there are already machine-consumeable documents of the Java syntax available?

I know that the JLS presents the syntax in one of it's chapters, but it's not that machine-consumeable as literals and rules are denoted by different font settings in a pdf.

There exists a machine-consumeable document containing the Java-5 syntax in the [Eclipse MoDisco project](http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/). However I'm also interested in the syntax of the other Java versions.

Comment: I would try to make use of the OpenJDK source as this is all machine consumable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Grammar files for Different Parsers

[Here](http://mindprod.com/javacc/java1.4.jj) is the JavaCC (Java Compiler Compiler) Grammar file for Java 1.4

[Here](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/GrammarTestGen/branches/Java1.5/Java15.g) is the ANTLR Grammar file for Java 1.5

Answer (score 1):

You might find useful information [on this page](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/), although I'm not sure what the status of the project is.

In particular, it refers to the [JLS #18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) which "presents a grammar for the Java programming language".